# How to make a feed generator for any webpages?

Tags: rss

[Feedity](http://feedity.com/) makes feeds address for any webpages and I would like to make an application like this.

How did they implement it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little like [yql](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), which can be used for something similar.  Given that HTML *can* be XML, and RSS feeds are XML as well, this should not be too difficult to implement.  If I were to approach a custom implementation of this, I would probably attempt the following:

1. Pull in html from the requested url
2. Cleanse the HTML so it could be converted to XML (or use something like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/))
3. Use XSLT to translate the XML document into an RSS feed based on a set of rules (that extract links, etc.)

All of that having been said, if I could use something like yql instead, I would definitely do that, as there can be a lot of pitfalls in the custom implementation (bad html, changing url's, defining rules, caching, etc.)